# main thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I see a code like this:

```
Thread.Sleep();
```

but never see 'Thread' declared.  Does 'Thread' refer to the main thread in C#?  I have seen other thread objects declared prior to use, but not this one.

Comment: Google. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx

Comment: See the MSDN article for the [Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zhz0ef8.aspx) method.

Answer (score 9):

This is a static method on the `System.Threading.Thread` class. It operates on the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

Thread is <strike>static</strike> sealed class.

Thread.Sleep() blocks the current thread.

Comment: Not quite. `Thread` is a `sealed` class (cannot be extended), but it is not a `static` class. `Sleep` is a `static` method however.

Answer (score 0):

> Does 'Thread' refer to the main thread in C#

Yes, It is the main thread you are working on and `Thread.Sleep()` is a static method of `System.Threading.Thread` class.

Comment: You say "yes", and then proceed to say that it acts on the current thread.  Keep in mind the current thread isn't always going to be the "main" thread.  The correct answer is no, followed by everything else you've said.